# Jquery append class based on condition

Tags: jquery

I want to add a .less class to a tr element if my var `number` is <100
This is what I've done so far, but it's not working as intended. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML CODE:

```
<table> 
   <thead>
       <tr> 
           <th>RESULT</th>
       </tr> 
   </thead> 
   <tbody>
   </tbody> 
</table>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var number = 80;
  if(number<100){
    $("tbody").append('<tr class="less">');
  }else{
    $("tbody").append('<tr>');
  }        
  $("tbody").append('<td>'+number+'</td>');
  $("tbody").append('</tr>');
});
```

CSS CODE:

```
tr.less {
  color:red;
}
```

([View it on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hkpvD))

Comment: This `.append('<tr>')` adds the entire `tr` element not simply a string of HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You have to append your `td` to the newly created `tr`, not the `tbody`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var number = 80;
  if(number<100){
    $("tbody").append('<tr class="less" />');
  }else{
    $("tbody").append('<tr />');
  }        
  $("tbody tr").append('<td>'+number+'</td>');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T9k6m/)

Answer (score 0):

It is appending correctly, but since you don't have any `td` with text in it, you cannot see it, use a developer tool and you'd see it

Answer (score 0):

```
$().ready(function() {
  var appendTr = function(threshold) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>').appendTo('tbody');
    if(threshold < 100) {
      tr.addClass('less');
    }
    $('<td/>').appendTo(tr).text('' + threshold);
    return tr;
  };
  var tr = appendTr(80);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append the closing tags to the wrong element .. try this approach..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var number = 80;

  $("tbody").append('<tr><td>'+number+'</td></tr>');
   if(number<100){
       $("tbody").find('tr:last').addClass('less')
  }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('<tr><td/></tr>').attr('class', number<100 ? 'less' : '').appendTo('tbody');
});
```